# Как убрать GET параметры из URL?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, url, get, redirect

Необходимо сделать редирект, если параметр "?start=" указан после корневого слеша (т.е. на главной странице). Например:

"site.com/?start=16" - должен перенаправлять на "site.com/"

"site.com/my-publishment?start=16" - должен оставаться как есть

Я пробовал такой код:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)start=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

но он перенаправляет меня во всех случаях, вместо того чтобы это делать только в первом

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bstart=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Регулярка `^$` как раз будет реагировать только запросы вида `site.com/?start=16`, то есть идущие к корню сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал сначала сам (код ниже), а потом попробовал еще вариант от @Visman. Оба варианта рабочие, если б только не одно "но": когда параметр start равен 16, он почему-то пропадает даже там, где должен оставаться. С остальными значениями этого параметра почему-то всё нормально. Мой код:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/\?start=[^&]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Работают: `/page?start=15`; `/page?start=17`; `/page?start=8`; `/page?start=32`...

Не работает: `/page?start=16`.