# Убрать get параметры только для главной страницы

Tags: .htaccess

Делаю так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Логично что срабатывает для всех страниц. А как сделать, чтобы правило работало только для главной страницы ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573035/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url

Comment: спасибо. Сам болбес я не нашел...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " /(?|/+|(.+?/)/+) "
RewriteRule .? /%1 [R=303,L]
```